# Changing another user's wallpaper

Tags: users, desktop-background

Is there anyway to change the wallpaper of another user? I believe a missing wallpaper file is preventing me from logging in to an account, and need to be able to change it.

Comment: Do you have access to the system, otherwise? (E.g., root/sudo.)

Comment: @JJ56, if all you need to do is to change the wallpaper to login to the other users account, why don't you just rename it then change it once you are logged in the other users account?

Comment: Yes, I was able to select the guest session and add another admin account. What exactly do  you suggest renaming?